# Drupal 7 Template Suggestions

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, theming

I think in Drupal 6- I needed to add the suggestion of 'node-NID' to the list of template files that were candidates for a node with an nid of 10. Supposedly this is already done in Drupal 7 and indeed I see 'node__10' in my node's theme_hook_suggestions. This should translate to 'node--10.tpl.php', but with that file in place (/sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates/node--10.tpl.php) I don't see the content in that file.

I've also tried node-10.tpl.php, page-node-10.tpl.php with varying numbers of hyphens to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting node--10.tpl.php in /sites/all/themes/mytheme instead of in the templates folder and be sure to clear the cache (admin/settings/performance) to allow Drupal to see the template override.

Comment: I actually could leave it where I had it but I wasn't clearing the cache. Which is something I usually do right away but didn't think I had to with tpl files. Thanks